# How to send List value in Request Body to Rest Api

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot, postman

Hi i have written a Rest Service to accept List of Long values as input via RequestBody and the code for the same is given below:

```
@DeleteMapping("/files")
public ResponseEntity<?> deletefiles(@RequestBody List<Long> ids) {
     fileService.deleteSelectedfiles(ids);
     return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

When i try to hit the above url from Postman i am getting the below error:

```
"JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: [![enter image description here][1]][1]Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]"
```

In Postman i am sending data as Raw data in the following format

```
{"ids": [1 ,2]}
```

Can anyone help me on this

Comment: Your request body isn't an array of numbers.

Comment: paste your js code function

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your payload is expected to be a

```
[1 ,2]
```

Instead of

```
{"ids": [1 ,2]}
```

The first option is a json array and the second example is a json body.
You can use the first one with your `@RequestBody List<Long> ids` or the second one with `@RequestBody YourData data` where

```
class YourData {
    List<Long> ids
}
```

Comment: I have tried with your suggestions @star67 but i am getting following exception:

org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?>

Answer (score 0):

```
@RequestMapping(YOUR_REQUEST_MAPPINGS)
public void testArrayOfValues(@RequestParam List<String> values) 
{
  
}
```